# ls starting at particular file

Tags: ls, filenames, sort

How do I `ls` files in a directory beginning with a particular filename?

For example, if my CWD has these files:

```
$ ls -1
alpha.mp3
bar.xls
file1.txt
file2.txt
foo.odt
testing3.txt
```

How do I print out the files starting at, say, "file2.txt":

```
file2.txt
foo.odt
testing3.txt
```

or at, say, "foo.odt":

```
foo.odt
testing3.txt
```

?

Comment: A bare `ls` will list every file, so this boils down to either telling `ls` to list specific files or post-processing the output of  `ls`. Are you more interested in one of those or the other?

Comment: Why do you want ls to start from a particular file, what's the real purpose?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Whatever works. A regex solution would be interesting, but so would a post-processing `sed` solution.

Comment: @memchr A process halted midway through processing my alphabetical list of files, and I want to resume it at the file it halted at.

Comment: @Geremia I'd highly recommend editing your post to describe the actual use-case, to avoid to post-processing route. It's really tempting to propose a post-processing solution, but those rely on parsing `ls` output, which can get tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [post-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/751230/ls-starting-at-particular-file#comment1429338_751230) solution, using `sed` or `awk`:

```
ls -1 | sed -n '/'"$filename"'/,$p'
```

or

```
ls -1 | awk '/'"$filename"'/,EOF'
```

where, e.g.,

```
filename='file2.txt'
```

<sup>-tip: StackOverflow "[Sed : print all lines after match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32569032/1429450)"</sup>

Answer (score 4):

If you use `zsh` as your shell, then you could use its *glob qualifiers* to select only those filenames that do not sort lexicographically before the chosen file<sup>1</sup>.

Ex. given

```
 % ls -1
alpha.mp3
bar.xls
file1.txt
file2.txt
foo.odt
testing3.txt
```

then define a helper function

```
 % nt() { ! [[ $NTREF > $REPLY ]] }
```

after which

```
 % NTREF=file2.txt; ls -1 -- *(+nt)
file2.txt
foo.odt
testing3.txt

 % NTREF=foo.odt; ls -1 -- *(+nt)
foo.odt
testing3.txt
```

You can use the qualified glob directly to pass the list to your stalled command

```
 % NTREF=foo.odt 
 % yourcommand -- *(+nt)
```

---

1. or even simpler, use `nt() { [[ $REPLY > $NTREF ]] }` then set `NTREF` to the name of the last file that *was* successfully processed

Comment: Interesting. Is there a similar way to do this in `bash`?

Comment: @Geremia not currently, so far as I know (that is, the lexical test construct is available in bash, but not the implementation of glob qualifiers. So you'd need to construct a list of files and loop over them explicitly - making it probably less efficient than [jeff-schaller's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/751244/65304) )

Answer (score 1):

To resume a process that was interrupted while iterating through a list of files, you could regenerate that list of files and then remove them until you get to the file you want to restart at:

```bash
set -- *
# see the "before" situation
printf '%s\n' "$@"
while [ "$1" != "file2.txt" ]
do
  shift
done
# check the results
printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

You could then run your process with that list of files:

```bash
$ your-process "$@"
```

The above assumes that your interrupted process was given the list of files in "natural" expanded order -- which is what `ls` would do if you don't specify the list of files.